# C++ Dynamically Allocate an Array, Bubblesort + Finding Average

Tags: c++

I have the bubblesort created and I think I have the average one too. Not sure. But I need to implement it into my main function and I'm not sure how to. Kind of stuck right now. Any help would be great. Thanks!

> Write a program that dynamically allocates an array large enough to
>   hold a user-defined number of test scores.
>
> Once all the scores are entered, the array should be passed to a
>   function (you create) as a pointer that sorts it in ascending order. 
>   This function can be named sortArray and will take two parameters:
>   (double* anArray, int size).  The function will return true if the
>   array is sorted, or false otherwise (for example if size <= 0)
>
> Another function should be created that calculates the average score
>   of the items in the array.  This function will take in two parameters
>   (double* anyArray, int size) and return the average as a double.
>
> The program should display the sorted array of scores and averages
>   with appropriate headings.
>
> Use pointer notation rather than array notation whenever possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool sortArray(double* anArray, int size);
double averageArray(double* anyArray, int size);


int main()

{
    double* anArray;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average;
    int scores;
    int count;

    cout << "How many test scores are you entering?: ";
    cin >> scores;

    anArray = new double[scores];

    cout << "Enter test scores: ";
    for (count = 0; count < scores; count++)
    {
        cout << "Test Score " << count + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> anArray[count];
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool sortArray(double* anArray, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (anArray[j] > anArray[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = anArray[j];
                anArray[j] = anArray[j + 1];
                anArray[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

double averageArray(double* anyArray, int size)
{
    double count = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        count += anyArray[i];
    }
    return (count / size);
}
```

Comment: Add `delete []anArray;` before `system("pause");` That will free memory that you dynamically allocated for your array. C++ doesn't collects memory garbage, so unfreed memory will leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used **bool in sortarray** function and it's never return any value so make it void and the you used **int temp** in sort array and it must be **double**, i fixed it for you use this code.
By the way you didn't called function and you forgot to print the value of array after sorting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool sortArray(double* anArray, int size);
double averageArray(double* anyArray, int size);


int main()

{
    double* anArray;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average;
    int scores;
    int count;

    cout << "How many test scores are you entering?: ";
    cin >> scores;

    anArray = new double[scores];

    cout << "Enter test scores: ";
    for (count = 0; count < scores; count++)
    {
        cout << "Test Score " << count + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> anArray[count];
    }

    sortArray(anArray, scores);

    for (count = 0; count < scores; count++)
    {
        cout << anArray[count] << "\n";
    }

    cout << averageArray(anArray, scores);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool sortArray(double* anArray, int size)
{
    bool sort = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if (anArray[j] > anArray[j + 1])
            {
                sort = true;
                double temp = anArray[j];
                anArray[j] = anArray[j + 1];
                anArray[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sort;
}

double averageArray(double* anyArray, int size)
{
    double count = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        count += anyArray[i];
    }

    return (count / (double) size);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I got the sortarray function to run but it's just returning what I originally inputted without ordering it? Also the function has to be bool because the function will return true if the array is sorted, or false otherwise (for example if size <= 0), so does that mean I have to add return true; under the if statemnt? Thanks.

Comment: I have change code as you want, check the code above and try this one now.

Comment: actually I forgot to change sortarray function to bool under main, and I just edited it.

Comment: Aha, yeah I saw that. Thank you! And I also think I figured out the average part by change the double *anyArray to anArray and then just doing cout << "Average: " << (count / scores); Is this the correct way?

Comment: no it works but it is not correct, you should use a return type for your function use this code it will works correctly. return (count / (double) size);

Comment: I found problem because you didn't call function again, I update code above take a look at it.

Comment: You're amazing, thank you. One more thing, let's say I wanted to pull the min and max from the already sorted array, how would I do it?

Comment: Would it be this? cout << "Min: " << anArray[0];
 cout << "Max: " << anArray[scores - 1];

Comment: if it's your answer please vote me, but about your question after sorting first one is min and last one is max.